# Dimension of kernel of a operator

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, vector-bundles

This question is simply applying a theorem. But I do not understand how . One can treat most of the content as black box. I will provide the definitions.

**The context:** 
I want to show

> If $M$ is a compact $n$-dimensional manifold, $P$ an ellipitic differential operator of order $k$, then $P:W^{k+l} \rightarrow W^l$ has kernel whose dimension is independent of $l$.

**Black box terminology explanation:**

---

**Definition:** Let $E_i \rightarrow M$ be two vector bundles, $P:\Gamma(M,E_0) \rightarrow \Gamma(M,E_1)$ is an [elliptic differential operator of order $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033672/definition-of-differential-operator), if locally  $P$ can be written as 
$$ Pf = \sum_{|\alpha| \le k } A^\alpha(y) \frac{\partial^\alpha}{\partial x_\alpha} f(y).$$

**Definition 2:** Let $E \rightarrow M$ be a complex vector bundle over a compact $n$-dimensional manifold. Then we can give the space of sections $\Gamma(M,E)$ a [Sobolev norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050956/showing-that-sobolev-norms-on-manifolds-are-equivalent). We denote $W^k$ be the completion of $\Gamma(M,E)$ with respect to this norm.

---

Let us suppose $P:W^{k+l} \rightarrow W^k$ is well defined and:

> **Theorem:** Let $Pu=f$, $f \in W^l$, $u \in W^r$ for some integer $r$, then $u \in W^{l+k}$.

---

It is claimed that then we have the kernel is independent of $l$.

---

**How does this follow?**

---

Reference: [Pg 48-49.](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/mainfile.pdf)

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that your definition for an elliptic operator is wrong (what you wrote is just the definition of a *linear* differential operator).

Comment: Of course, a linear differential operator is said to be elliptic if its principal symbol satisfies a non-degeneracy condition.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks  a lot. I will add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $u \in W^{k+r}$ lies in the kernel of $P,$ so $Pu = 0.$ Then as $0 \in W^{\ell}$ for each $\ell,$ so the elliptic regularity theorem gives $u \in W^{k+\ell}$ for all $\ell.$ So if $N_r \subset W^{k+r}$ is the null space of $P$ viewed as an operator $W^{k+r} \rightarrow W^r,$ we get $N_r \subset N_{\ell}$ for each $\ell.$ As $r$ was also arbitrary, we see that $N_r$ is independent of $r$ and hence its dimension also is.